# Microsoft's CopyFileEx error

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-copying, windows-api-code-pack

I am using Microsoft's CopyFileEx method to copy  files. 
I am coping from one server to another and the file located in share folder and i am using UNC.
i get an error 999. I was able to find the ‘999’ error on Microsoft’s Technet site. The copies are failing because of an “Error performing inpage operation.” 
According to the following Microsoft kb article found at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141117 , some of the causes of  “Error performing inpage operation” are:
“Errors caused by network connectivity can cause these errors. Mismatched MTU sizes or truncation of a packet at a router can result in this error when files larger than the largest packet size are copied over the network. In essence, the network connection is the media that has the physical problem.”

but after some investigation i saw that the file are small and I couldnt fint network issue.

I am desperate for idea...

Comment: Talk to the LAN admin about this problem.  He can get help at serverfault.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says in the beginning of that kb article that if it's a small file, it can be an I/O error that causes it to give error 999 due to the way it's copying the file.

I'd suggest trying to copy the file manually using [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (as mentioned in that article) and hopefully that would give you the real error since you avoid the memory mapping.

Comment: but my KB is refer to Windows CopyFile() API and I used Windows CopyFileEx()

Comment: @MoShe: Sorry, I didn't notice that. However, I'd assume that there's a fair chance that it could be the same issue with both of them since they could be using the same or similar code for parts of their operations. Either way, I'd suggest that the first step is still to see what error you get (if any) if you try to copy the file using some other method.